# Kotlin: Operator '==' cannot be applied to 'kotlin.Int' and 'Person?' Error

Tags: kotlin

I have the following code from the "Kotlin In Action" MEAP book that is supposed to find the maximum age of people in the group and return all people of that age:

```
data class Person(val name: String, val age: Int)
val people = listOf(Person("Alice", 29), Person("Bob", 31))
people.filter {it.age == people.maxBy(Person::age)}
```

However, I am receiving the following error:  "Kotlin: Operator '==' cannot be applied to 'kotlin.Int' and 'Person?'."  How do I fix the code to make it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kotlin's `maxBy` function (https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/max-by.html) returns `T?` for an iterable of T (like a list of T's).

Therefore, `people.maxBy(Person::age)` returns a value of type `Person?`, but you're trying to compare it to an integer. You can compare the age of this `Person?` if you wish:

```
people.filter { it.age == people.maxBy(Person::age)?.age }
```

Will output `[Person(name=Bob, age=31)]` for your sample.

Answer (score 9):

Use `map` + `max` instead of `maxBy`. Also extract the maximum value to a variable to avoid computing it multiple times:

```
data class Person(val name: String, val age: Int)
val people = listOf(Person("Alice", 29), Person("Bob", 31))
val maxAge = people.map(Person::age).max()
people.filter { it.age == maxAge }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
list = people.groupBy{ it.age }.maxBy{ it.key }?.value
```

Comment: So, why my solution which works is being downvoted? It returns a list of people with the maximum age. Other solutions are more inefficient as they requires to calculate the maximum per every comparison.